# How to disable digest in asset pipeline grails

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, grails-2.5

I am using asset pipeline 2.5.0 and Grails 2.5.0, while creating a war all the static files like js, css, etc are renamed ( a digest gets appended to it ). Is there a way to avoid the renaming or to disable the digest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general asset-pipeline should always leave a file with the original filename if you are not actively skipping this feature

```
grails.assets.skipNonDigests
```

http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/configuration.html

As digesting is part of the bundling process and needed to bust caches i highly recommend not disabling that in production but if you still want to you should be able to disable it by also disabling the bundling

```
grails.assets.bundle=false
```

Comment: thanks..adding grails.assets.skipNonDigests = false; in my config.groovy worked..

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @peschenbach helped me. But the issue was also with my asset-pipeline plugin which was 2.5.1. I updated it to 2.7.3 and added these lines in my Config.groovy

```
grails.assets.enableDigests = false // this will disable appending digest to minified static files
grails.assets.skipNonDigests = false // this will not skip the non digest files
```

The **enableDigests** flag was not present in 2.5.1 which disables renaming of the files.
Whereas **skipNonDigests** will also add the file with original names in the asset folder.
Hope this helps others.